# Ignore battery optimization permission ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS is getting denied on Xiaomi android 11 devices

Tags: android, android-11, xiaomi

In our android app we ask for ignore battery optimization permission, and the user has an option to allow or deny the permission

On some Xiaomi android 11 devices , even when the user clicks allow permission , it brings back. But when the user manually searches for Battery Optimization setting and selects dont optimise , and retries granting it through our app , the permission for ignoring battery optimization is granted

We are not able to grant ignore battery optimization permission on Xiaomi devices programmatically when we follow the android standard by using ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS to white list our app

On other devices users are able to grant the permission through our app

I am not sure if there is any bug from MIUI on android 11 devices that doesn't allow apps to stop battery optimization

Can anyone suggest a workaround on how do we programmatically disable battery optimization on xiaomi devices running on android 11 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission to disable battery optimization keeps appearing on Android API 28 despite not being changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64554339/permission-to-disable-battery-optimization-keeps-appearing-on-android-api-28-des)

Comment: @miralj have you find solution for the above issue?